# If condition not working inside the onClick button

Tags: android, android-button

The if condition is not called inside the button's onClick(View v). What should i do?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String k;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText j = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    public void nih(View v) {
        EditText j = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        if (j.equals("hello")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("nishan", "london");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before asking

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text value of the `EditText (j)`, as follows:

```
j.getText().toString().equals("hello")
```

Beside, it will be better to not recall `findViewById` to retrieve (again) this EditText. You already have it in `onCreate`, therefore, your code should be:

```
EditText j; // make a global var

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    j = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); // get its id
}

public void nih(View v) {
    if (j.getText().toString().equals("hello")) { // use it
        ...
    }
}
```